# Extracting alt attribute from image into div (Gallery description purpose)

Tags: jquery, attributes, alt

So i have this mini gallery. This is how i want it to work: 
img BIG IMAGE img
div description div
img thumbnails img

Everyting works fine except i don't know if i'm extracting alt value correctly into div. Code inc:

HTML SAMPLE:

```
<p><img id="largeImg" src="zdjecia/bawialnia.jpg" alt="Large image" /></p> 
  <div id="opis"></div>
<p class="thumbs">

 <a href="zdjecia/bawialnia.jpg" title="Bawialnia"><img src="zdjecia/bawialnia-thumb.jpg" alt="some description" /></a>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("h2").append('<em></em>')

 $(".thumbs a").click(function(){

   var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
   var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");

   var altText = $(this).attr("alt");


   $("#largeImg").attr({ src: largePath, alt: largeAlt });

   $("div#opis").html(altText);

   $("h2 em").html(" (" + largeAlt + ")"); return false;
 });

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you find yourself writing `$(this)` repeatedly, you might consider doing it once and caching the result instead. *Every* call to `$(...)` results in several function calls and a memory allocation or two. Three calls in a click handler isn't really going to matter, but it's a bad habit to get into. Try `var $this = $(this);` then `$this.attr("href")`, `$this.attr("title")`, etc. FWIW. (If you're creating closures, you may want to clear that var at the end of your function, e.g. `$this = undefined;` -- unless, of course, it's useful to the closures.)

Comment: And use english when naming your classes/ids or you will make other (god save non polish developers) who could work with your code cry - consistence is even more important - everything english or polish - your choice just be consistent. 

Even if now you aren't working with foreign developers it's a good habit to practice from start. English is common language for all programmers.

Answer (score 6):

Using `$(this).attr("alt")` in that context is returning the alt attribute of the a tag, not the child img.

Try this:

```
var altText = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
```